# How to effectively reduce the track-pad sensitivity more than system preferences will let you (OS X Lion)

Tags: macos, mouse, osx-lion, touchpad

I am using a Magic Trackpad, and I have turned the sensitivity all the way down in System Preferences, but it's not slow/insensitive enough. I have a gaming mouse that has custom DPI settings, and I can make it so that moving the mouse about 6 inches across the mouse pad moves the cursor on-screen only about 100 pixels, which is closer to what I want, but I can't seem to find a way to do this with the trackpad.

Can someone point me in the direction of a method to slow down the cursor further while using a Magic Trackpad? Perhaps there is a piece of software out there that allows further customization of the Magic Trackpad's performance, or some similar solution?

Comment: Are you using two different pointing devices at the same time (eg the trackpad *and* a mouse)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the few-and-far-between "tools" available for Mac, all of which failed miserably, I ended up simply writing a basic background script that allowed for me to truly control the cursor speed. This was the only way I found to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the BetterTouchTool, http://cl.eye.rs/index.php?u=217994, where you can adjust the tracking speed.

Comment: It was a good suggestion, but it looks like you can only boost the speed with that tool, not lower it. Thank you anyway!